# Duplicate paste when using a virtual keyboard

Tags: python, winapi, win32com

I want to write a copy and paste image function for the application simulation windows OS.

Step1:open a image

Step2:write to clipborad

Step3:use `win32api.keybd_event` to press `"ctrl+V"`

As a result,about 3% image was replaced by the image after image suppose to be and the total image number will never change.

My OS is windows7 Enterprise Edition.
I guess it may caused by the lag when pressing `"ctrl+V"`,but the total image number is exact.
When I slow down the process,duplicate rate goes down but still exist even at the speed of one image per second.

I also check the clipboard,`win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB)` returns different values when duplicate copies pastes.

```
import hashlib
import time
import traceback
import win32api
import win32clipboard as clip
from io import BytesIO
import win32con
from PIL import Image


def setImage(data):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    try:
        clip.OpenClipboard()  
        clip.EmptyClipboard()  
        clip.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB, data) 
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        return m.hexdigest()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        setImage(data)

def copyPicMain(imagePath, width = 600, height = 480, internal=0, notResize = False):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    try:
        clip.OpenClipboard()
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        pre_md5 = m.hexdigest()
    except TypeError:
        # if clip is empty
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('empty')
        pre_md5 = ''
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        clip.OpenClipboard()
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        pre_md5 = m.hexdigest()
    img = Image.open(imagePath)
    output = BytesIO()
    if not notResize:
        img = img.resize((height, width), Image.BILINEAR)
    img.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
    data = output.getvalue()[14:]
    output.close()
    new_md5 = setImage(data)
    print(pre_md5, new_md5)
    time.sleep(internal)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)  # ctrl key code 17
    win32api.keybd_event(86, 0, 0, 0)  # v key code 86
    win32api.keybd_event(86, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # key up 
    time.sleep(internal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imagePathList = [r'C:\Users\F1235648\PycharmProjects\copyPic\pic\Picture-007 ANT Polar Power.png',r'C:\Users\F1235648\PycharmProjects\copyPic\pic\Picture-008 LTE Max Power QPSK 12 0.png',r'C:\Users\F1235648\PycharmProjects\copyPic\pic\Picture-009 LTE Max Power QPSK 12 19.png']
    for imagePath in imagePathList:
        copyPicMain(imagePath)
```

Cycle more times until it goes wrong,maybe computer performance is one of the reasons
The result is shown below
[ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE4jD.png)
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFB8w.png)

Comment: Can you provide some pasted screenshots to illustrate the problem more specifically?

Comment: In addition, according to MSDN, `keybd_event` has been replaced. You can try `SendInput` api.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshots.And if I want to use SendInput api ,which package I should use?ctype?The msdn documentation says that SendInput only extends certain features, but the result is the same as keybd_event.It also says that GetAsyncKeyState api can check for synchronization issues.As I can see,GetAsyncKeyState api only return a code 1/0 to let you see the key is pressed or not,has no conncetions with synchronization issues.

Comment: So, when you copy and paste at a slower speed, is there still a situation where the image is replaced?

Comment: Slower speed helps,but the situation still exists

Comment: When I try your code, I will report an error. I will change `copyPicMain (imagePathList)` to `copyPicMain (imagePath)`. I don't know why this problem occurs in my compiler.

Comment: Sorry,that's just a handwriting mistake.Just forget it